# Jquery CSS Color not updating list bullet points

Tags: jquery, html, css

Having trouble getting the bullet points/numbers in a list to change color along with the rest of the list when changing the color using jquery.

Using:
**$('ul li').css('color', '#2b2b2b');**

This changes the color of the text in the list entry, but yet the bullet point stays the original color.

[Before changing color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDBjx.png) 
[After changing color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3UuX.png)

Does anyone know how to get around this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search before posting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306640/setting-bullet-colors-in-ul-li-lists-via-css-without-using-images-or-span-tags

Comment: @turbopipp, I don't think it's the same question

Comment: @im1dermike, care to elaborate?

Comment: It actually seems to be true only when event driven, and specifity doesn't seem to help. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/prycc8gs/1/)

Comment: @JNF this is the exact problem that we are having, as shown on your fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ordered/unordered list [working jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/jpbgagoL/)

```js
$(function () {
    $("#change").on("click",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('ul > li, ol > li').css({'color': 'red','list-style-type': 'none'});
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('ul > li').css('list-style-type', 'initial');
            $('ol > li').css('list-style-type', 'decimal');
        }, 1);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
</ol>
<ul>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
</ul>
<button id="change">Change color</button>
```

Comment: Worked with this, seemed the easiest way to work alongside using some of the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

After some tinkering I've found that list style elements can't be animated. If you want the color of the bullets to change dynamically you need to redefine the `list-style-type` and change it to another value so it can be repainted by the browser.

Check the updated fiddle demonstrating the described behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/prycc8gs/2/

Comment: This seems to work well.
Is there not a way to keep the old list style when changing color?

I tried setting to something different and then changing back, but no luck.

Comment: You can render list-style-type to none, then set a timeout to 1 millisecond and render it back to the initial values. See my example code below

Answer (score 1):

To combine and imrpove @henser & @turbopipp

The default list style seems not to change color when triggering events (document ready excluded).

You can, however, switch to another style and back

```
$('ul > li').css('color', "green");
$('ul > li').css('list-style-type', 'square');
$('ul > li').css('color', "cyan");
$('ul > li').css('list-style-type', 'disc');
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/prycc8gs/5/)

Or, if you have access and want to play with the css, the second piece of advice stands - making the bullet yourself.

Comment: This only works due to the alert in your fiddle, will not work without sadly.

Comment: Apparently, it needs something like a setTimeout(link fixed)

Answer (score -2):

You can also do it in jQuery with the `.click()` event.

This example is with numbers:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#change").click(function() {
        $('ol').css('color', 'red');
    })
});
```

```css
ol { 
  counter-reset: item; 
}

ol li { 
  display: block; 
}

ol li:before {
  content: counter(item) ". ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>
<button id="change">Change text color</button>
```

Comment: This would work for the bullets yes.
Does anyone have a solution for numbered lists though?

Comment: @Lewis Is pure css an option? Any reason you're using jquery?

Comment: @JNF We are using jquery to update the list colors, the list will use its standard color defined in css unless the user sets it to something different from a range of options (accessibility for hard of sight)

Comment: Sry I didn`t read the question right. Now I have an example with numbers. This is a little bit different, but it works also...

Comment: See my example below, updated it to support numbered lists

Comment: Yeah also a great solution :)