# How to change the color of list node

Tags: css

I want to make a list where the list node and list item turn red when hovered. Here is the example code:

```
<style>
        ul li a:hover {
            color: red;
        }
</style>
<ul>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">2</a></li>
</ul>
```

With this code the numbers turn red when hovered, but the nodes don't. How can I change the color of the nodes as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Bullet colors in UL/LI html lists via CSS without using any images or span tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306640/how-to-set-bullet-colors-in-ul-li-html-lists-via-css-without-using-any-images-or)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it to the node too:

```
ul li a:hover,ul li:hover    {
   color: red;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/33a06m8d/)