# Get second line of bullet item to indent as first part - not underneath the bullet?

Tags: html, css

When an item in my bulleted list is long enough to wrap, I need the wrapped part to line up on the left with the first line, starting to the right of the bullet, rather than starting underneath the bullet.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

At the moment I've got the following code.

**CSS** and **HTML**

```css
.row2 {
      padding: 20px 20px 5px 20px;
      height: auto;
      overflow: hidden;
   max-width: 500px; }

    .red-square-5 {
      width:5px;
   height:5px;
   background:#f00;
   display:inline-block; }
```

```html
<div class="row2">
<p><div class="red-square-5"></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;Long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long title</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use `<ul>` and `<li>`?

Comment: Not an especially good one. Partly I want to tinker with the bullet definition in the CSS; partly my avoiding `<ul>` and `<li>` is just a foible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take on this would be to include the bullet in another div and then wrap both divs in a container div.

```css
.row2 {
    padding-left: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 500px; 
}
.red-square-5 {
    position:absolute;
    width:5px;
    height:5px;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    background:#f00; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container-div">
    <div class="red-square-5"></div>
    <div class="row2">
        Long long long long long long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long long long long long long 
        long long long title
    </div>
</div>
```

And this would be the solution using unordered list, as seen here: [How to set Bullet colors in UL/LI html lists via CSS without using any images or span tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306640/how-to-set-bullet-colors-in-ul-li-html-lists-via-css-without-using-any-images-or)

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  padding-left: 1em; 
  text-indent: -0.8em;
}

li::before {
  content: "■ ";
  color: red; /* or whatever color you prefer */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long lng long long long long long long title
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: My mistake, misunderstood what "first line" meant in the question.

Comment: So fix is inline-block on whole div?

Comment: No, it is to have 2 divs, but there is a better way with `<ul><li>`, I'll add it later if I have time.

Comment: Cool! Maybe my answer is the ul solution you mean? Or hopefully close :D

Comment: I've clarified the question.

Comment: @DaniSpringer It is a bit different, it uses li:before to add a custom red  bullet.

Comment: Right! I should have thought of that _before_.

Comment: @DaniSpringer nice pun :)

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but do I need to define `container-div` in the CSS and if the answer is "yes, and you can make the definition null", how should I do that?

Comment: @ruffle, No you don't need to define `container-div`. The only reason I put it there is to give a wrapper to the block - for instance, if you want to iterate through the list items or delete one or whatnot, you have one `div` to reference instead of two.

Comment: Many thanks for explaining this. That may indeed make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

I'll consider a related case in which you can't use UL to handle the hanging indent: checkboxes.

Checkboxes have *always* been presented with hanging indents. It is a source of wonder that there is no baked-in support for this. But anyway...

The old-school way is with a table. This works but may offend purists.

Aydin's use of the CSS `text-indent` attribute can be used with a block element the content of which starts with `<input type="checkbox" />`. Note that it need not be a `div`. Any element styled as a block will be fine. It is also possible to use glyphicons (Bootstrap) and handle user input events yourself. If you want to do this but still use data-binding then set the value of an `<input type="hidden">` and you can bind that. Be aware that you may need to explicitly trigger binding updates when setting the value programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

to archieve that so, get the line of "long long long long long long long long long long long long long long title" and add this ascii character; " & n b s p ;"
Source: [&nbsp and HTML Space Challenges and Tricks](https://mailtrap.io/blog/nbsp/#:%7E:text=is%20a%20useful%20way,used%20just%20for%20that%20purpose.)

add enough until you get the right position.