# Wordpress: Changing bullet colors (not text) of an specific ul

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to change the bullet `color` on my website. I understand that I need to use custom `CSS` to alter the theme.

I have found a solution that do change the color. However, bullets are also added before each of my my menus across the top of the screen and on my dashboard controls.

[image: screenshot]

I want to change the color of the bullets to my custom color without adding the bullets to the other menus?

live site: [link to site](http://danceswithbass.com/radio-khmd/february-2018/the-wild-feathers-the-ceiling/)

Comment: Replace the css you have with mine and it should do.. basically just target the class to that specific `<ul>` , but please read my note as well. hope it helps you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Bullet colors in UL/LI html lists via CSS without using any images or span tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306640/how-to-set-bullet-colors-in-ul-li-html-lists-via-css-without-using-any-images-or)

Comment: @ravipatel its not his just not familiar targeting a specific `class`. The Bullet custom color he already solved.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly. I really appreciate your help! - rick

Answer (score 0):

First you have to point to this **specific** `<ul>` and since the nearest `class` to it is within the `<div>` tag, using `div` :  `class` which is : `entry-content` should do it. **This is what you are missing.**

Then to place it before the text, use `::before`. This part you already did correct.

Here is an example:

```css
.entry-content ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


.entry-content li::before {
  content: "•";
  padding-right: 7px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
<ul>
<li><span style="font-size: 18pt;">Track: <em>The Ceiling</em></span></li>
<li><span style="font-size: 18pt;">Artist: The Wild Feathers</span></li>
<li><span style="font-size: 18pt;">Album: <em>The Wild Feathers</em></span></li>
<li><span style="font-size: 18pt;">Year: 2013</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Extra** : i would give this `<ul>` an unique `id` and rather point to that, but my solution would work for this page, thing is on other pages it might also display as custom bullets, if those pages have a class called `entry-content`.