# Is it possible to have an unordered list with bullets inside and hanging indent?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Is it possible to have an unordered list with the following?

1. No padding
2. No margin
3. Hanging indent
4. Markers inside, i.e. not in the (non-existent) padding

It seems that with `list-style-position: outside` I cannot have (4) and it seems that with `list-style-position: inside` I cannot have (3).

If having (1)–(4) is not possible then I guess I could give up (1) and (4) and use `list-style-position: outside` together with some `left-padding`, but is there a magic value that will give a consistent look across browsers?

https://jsfiddle.net/1yf2eq3b/

UPDATE: It seems that wrapping the list items in an `display: inline-block` div makes the `list-style-position: inside` solution work for list items with `<br>` line breaks, but it still does not work for list items with automatic line breaks.

Comment: build a custom bullets using pseudo element and you will have full control

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/5306640/8620333

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
ul { 
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #DEDEDE; // only to demonstrate left list edge
}
    
ul>li { list-style: none; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>&#007; test</li>
  <li>&#007; test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li> &nbsp;&nbsp; test</li>
  <li>&#007; test<br>&#007; test</li>
</ul>
```

It seems like you "could" force this if you use a double `&nbsp;` as a substitute for the padding neccessary to match the indent and line up the text properly.

Note: insert the ascii character of your choice