# CSS Design for order list

Tags: html, css

I have HTML and CSS like this to which i want to make design.

css:

```
ol li {list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;}
```

HTML:

```
<ol>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three
<ol>
<li>Three.One</li>
<li>Three.Two</li>
</ol>
</li>
<li>Four</li>
</ol>
```

Now with this above is my HTML and CSS content. As you can see i dont want to use any span element or anchor tag with this order list. So, can i make different color for OL(order list) number and text content of li? I want to make red color for number and black color for li content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of (my own question, from some time ago): [How to colour the list-style-type auo-generated numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725741/how-to-colour-the-list-style-type-auto-generated-numbers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/kefvT/1/).

```css
ol li {
  list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;
}

ol {
  counter-reset: li;
}

ol li {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-increment: li;
  position: relative;
}

ol li:before {
  content: counter(li, decimal-leading-zero) ".";
  position: absolute;
  left: -2.6em;
  width: 2em;
  text-align: right;
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three
    <ol>
      <li>Three.One</li>
      <li>Three.Two</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ol>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Nathan...really thanks ...It's working fine.And looks great. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
ol {
    counter-reset: li;  
    list-style: none;
}

li:before {
    counter-increment: li;                                               
    content: counter(li, decimal-leading-zero)". ";  
    color: red;      
}
```

or

```
ol {
  counter-reset: li;  
  list-style: none;
}

li:before {
  counter-increment: li;                                               
  content: counters(li, ".", decimal-leading-zero) ". ";  
  color: red;      
}
```

or

```
ol {
  counter-reset: li;  
  list-style: none;
}

li:before {
  counter-increment: li;                                               
  content: "0" counters(li, ".") " ";  
  color: red;      
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/laser_apple/LKWhw/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
ol {color: #ff0000;}
ol li { color: #000000; }
```

Comment: @sudz..
actually It's not working.Because it's taking black color for whole UL LI.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
li {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    margin-left: 2em;
}
li:before {
    display: inline-block;
    color: red;
    content: counter(item, decimal-leading-zero);
    counter-increment: item;
    width: 2em;
    margin-left: -2em;
}
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/HNmDK/1/).

Comment: And what about `ol li {list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;}`?

Comment: that means it's starting with 01, 02, etc

so i want to give red color this digits only and black color to content only

Comment: What exactly is this missing?

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS should do the trick:

```
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: count;
  margin: .8em 0;
  padding: 0; }
  ol ol {
    margin: 0; }
  ol li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 2em; }
    ol li:before {
      counter-increment: count;
      content: counter(count, decimal-leading-zero) ".\00a0";
      display: inline-block;
      min-width: 2em;
      margin-left: -2em;
      text-align: right;
      color: red; }
```

<kbd>**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dC8vQ/1/)**</kbd>

This solution relies on [CSS Counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Counters) to keep track of the decimal number that should be displayed. `content: counter(count) ".\00a0";` outputs the current value of the `count` counter, followed by a period and [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). The `:before` psuedo-element is styled as an inline-block element and a negative margin pulls it to the left onto the `LI` padding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some tricks here that using :before pseudo elements

```
ol li{
    list-style:none;
    counter-increment:li;
    color:#27ae60;
}
ol li:before{
    content:counter(li, decimal-leading-zero)'.';
    color:#c0392b;
    padding-right:5px;
}
```

Have a look at the demo [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/qiqiabaziz/CwXLL/1/).