# Want to make the number on a ordered list a different color and size

Tags: html, css, html-lists

So I was wondering how I can change the color, size and font of the ordered list numbers. I am aware of how to make the color different but I am wondering how to make the color different. Here is the code I have so far

```css
/* Color scheme: #6FC2F0 (Blue) #74E2AE(Green) and #ff00ff (Fuchsia or purple) #FC913A (Orange)*/


/* Fonts: Alegreya Sans, Kalam and Actor */

.topnav {
  background-color: #6FC2F0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 20px;
  font: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #74E2AE;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.rectitle {
  font-size: 50px;
  font: 'Actor', cursive;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.byx {
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #8C8C8C;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.byx a {
  color: #FC913A;
}

.ingred {
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font: 'Actor', sans-serif;
}

.ingredients {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.serv {
  font-size: 20px;
  font: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.instructions {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.ol li {
  color: #ff00ff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Actor|Alegreya+Sans|Kalam" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="recipe.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="#about">About Us</a>
    <a href="#wheel">Wheel</a>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  </div>
  <div class="rectitle">
    Easy 3 Step Honey-Sriracha Salmon
  </div>
  <div class="byx">
    By: Varun J -- Read more
    <a href="#aboutus">Here</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ingredients">
    <h1>Ingredients:</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="serv">
    Serves 1 person
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <div class="ingred">
    <p>Salmon:</p>
    <p>1 Medium sized Salmon</p>
    <p>Salt and Pepper (to taste)</p>
    <p>Sauce:</p>
    <p>1 tablespoon Sriracha</p>
    <p>1 tablespoon Honey</p>
    <p>1/2 tablespoon Lime Juice</p>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <div class="instructions">
    <h1>Preperation:</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="prep">
    <ol>
      <li class="listi"><span style="color: black">test</span></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JSSSSS/y3mcp2t8/1/

Please bear with me as I am not exactly the best HTML/CSS coder.

Comment: Can you clarify more about what the problem is? I believe you have a spelling error as you wrote "I am aware of how to make the color different but I am wondering how to make the color different."

Comment: HTML/CSS does not have a way to color list style numbers. Having said that there is a workaround I just found here: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/color-bullets.en.html ... give it a try.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's great that you added some code to your question. This always helps get quick answers. It'd be even better if in the future you show us only the most relevant part of the code and not the whole thing . Just as much as needed to reproduce the problem you're facing. (Also, there must be a word or two missing in your first paragraph. Please fix.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same technique, using nested spans to keep auto numbering, and allow to style numbers and text:

```css
.preplist {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.preplist2 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.listobject {
  color: green;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ol>
        <span class="preplist"><li><span class="listobject">test</span></li></span>
        <span class="preplist2"><li><span class="listobject">test2</span></li></span>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do.

In the css file:

```
ol li {
  list-style: none;
}

.number {
   color: red;
}
```

In html:

```
<ol>
  <li><span class="number">1. </span>item</li>
</ol>
```

As you can see, you'll have to write the numbers. That is, they won't be autogenerated any longer. But there may be more complicated solutions to that problem. See here: [How to colour the list-style-type auto-generated numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725741/how-to-colour-the-list-style-type-auto-generated-numbers)

[Code above also here: https://jsfiddle.net/asifmeh/5dmr8zfL/3/]